# MySQL: Materializing table function take so long

Tags: query-performance, innodb

Thanks for checking my question

I encountered a strange issue. the same query in same db return different actual time

here is explain analyze statement

```
explain analyze
SELECT COUNT(1) AS `cnt`
FROM `word_tbl` `Word`
WHERE word like '%%'
  AND id in (select distinct(wt.id)
             from word_tbl wt,
                  json_table(wt.items, '$[*]'
                             columns (isNecessary tinyint path '$.isNecessary', nested path '$.meanings[*]' columns (meanings varchar(100) PATH '$'))) as jt1
             where wt.is_unnecessary = false
               and jt1.isNecessary = 1
               and jt1.meanings is null)
  AND ('ADJ' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR 'ADV' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR
       'CONJ' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR 'NOUN' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR
       'PHRASE' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR 'PRON' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR
       'VERB' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR 'PREP' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')) OR
       'INTERJ' MEMBER OF ( JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].pos')))
  and json_extract(items, '$[*].pos') IS NOT NULL
```

slow one

```
-> Aggregate: count(1)  (actual time=60574.661..60574.661 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop semijoin  (actual time=0.292..60567.422 rows=23576 loops=1)
        -> Filter: ((Word.word like '%%') and (<cache>('ADJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('ADV') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('CONJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('NOUN') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PHRASE') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PRON') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('VERB') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PREP') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('INTERJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos'))) and (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos') is not null))  (cost=12201.28 rows=12742) (actual time=0.038..789.416 rows=73748 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on Word  (cost=12201.28 rows=114686) (actual time=0.023..229.585 rows=105850 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop inner join  (actual time=0.810..0.810 rows=0 loops=73748)
            -> Filter: (wt.is_unnecessary = false)  (cost=0.28 rows=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=73748)
                -> Single-row index lookup on wt using PRIMARY (id=Word.id)  (cost=0.28 rows=1) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=73748)
            -> Filter: (jt1.meanings is null)  (actual time=0.877..0.877 rows=0 loops=67791)
                -> Materialize table function  (actual time=0.877..0.877 rows=0 loops=67791)
```

fast one

```
-> Aggregate: count(1)  (actual time=1634.001..1634.001 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop semijoin  (actual time=0.873..1631.175 rows=23576 loops=1)
        -> Filter: ((Word.word like '%%') and (<cache>('ADJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('ADV') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('CONJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('NOUN') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PHRASE') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PRON') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('VERB') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('PREP') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos')) or <cache>('INTERJ') member of (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos'))) and (json_extract(Word.items,'$[*].pos') is not null))  (cost=12200.78 rows=12741) (actual time=0.061..528.244 rows=73748 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on Word  (cost=12200.78 rows=114681) (actual time=0.035..108.736 rows=105850 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop inner join  (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=73748)
            -> Filter: (wt.is_unnecessary = false)  (cost=0.28 rows=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=73748)
                -> Single-row index lookup on wt using PRIMARY (id=Word.id)  (cost=0.28 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=73748)
            -> Filter: (jt1.meanings is null)  (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=67791)
                -> Materialize table function  (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=67791)
```

In slow one, Materialize table function takes so long (actual time = 0.877) but, fast one actual time = 0.014

I knew table schema is not good and query needs to be optimized.
I want to know why materialization take so long and why the actual times of execution are different

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `word like '%%'` from the query; it probably slows things down unnecesarily.
- Use RDMS relationships; don't hide information in JSON that you need to search on.
- Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )` it is often slow.  Instead consider `JOIN` or `EXISTs`.
- Probably things like `and jt1.isNecessary = 1` can be moved out of the subquery and into the outer query.

Most of those explain poor performance; some apply the the schema, too.